# Wordpress Admin customization and Wrapping Select Elements

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress-theming

Wordpress Admin customization and Wrapping Select Elements

I want to customize the select elements in Wordpress Admin but css required to wrap this selects with another div with select class.

For example class-wp-list-table.php line 462 in Wordpress version 4.8.3

How can I wrao those elements without editing the orjinal file.

Comment: with javascript

Comment: I wonder if there is any other way I can do it